# Why does my shiny app give a Warning: Error in !: invalid argument type error when using a custom function to build a plotly plot?

Tags: r, shiny, plotly, rlang, custom-function

I'm trying to build a custom function to display a plotly plot of counts in my Shiny app. I want to make a function because this app has 4 versions of this plot. The function has 5 inputs:

```
resource_plots <- function (data, group_variable, group_filter = NULL, title)
```

The first argument is the data. The second is the name of the column to visualize. The 3rd is the users to add lines to the chart by specific levels of the first variable. The final one is the title for the plot.

To make it work, this custom functions takes the input into account, but it also uses the sym() function on the group_variable. I keep getting this warning and don't see any plot, and I can't figure out why:

```
Warning: Error in !: invalid argument type
```

Here's a reduced version of my code:

```
library(tidyr)
library(shiny)
library(plotly)
library(dplyr)
library(rlang)
library(stringr)

my_data <- tibble(employee = c("Justin", "Corey","Sibley", "Justin", "Corey","Sibley", "Lisa", "NA"),
                  education = c("graudate", "student", "student", "student", "student", "student", "student", "student"),
                  fte_max_capacity = c(1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5),
                  project = c("big", "medium", "small", "medium", "small", "small", "medium", "medium"),
                  aug_2021 = c(2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 5),
                  sep_2021 = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 50),
                  oct_2021 = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 12),
                  nov_2021 = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 10))

# Define UI for application that draws a histogram
ui <- fluidPage(
    
    # Sidebar with a slider input for number of bins 
    sidebarLayout(
        sidebarPanel(
            selectInput("group_choice", label = h3("group_choice"), 
                        choices = unique(my_data$project),
                        selected = unique(my_data$project),
                        multiple = TRUE),
            selectInput("resource_choice", label = h3("resource_choice"), 
                        choices = unique(my_data$employee),
                        multiple = TRUE)),
        
        # Show a plot of the generated distribution
        mainPanel(
            plotOutput("distPlot")
        )
    )
)


# Define server logic required to draw a histogram
server <- function(input, output) {
    
    
    
    employee_list <- c(NA_character_)
    
    employee_list <- reactive({
        req(input$resource_choice)
        input$resource_choice
    })
    
    
    resource_plots <- function(data, group_variable, group_filter = NULL, title) {
        
        group_variable <- sym(group_variable)
        variable_list <- c("big")
        
        base_data <- data %>%
            dplyr::group_by(!!group_variable) %>%
            summarise_at(vars(contains("_20")), sum, na.rm = TRUE) %>%
            pivot_longer(-{{group_variable}}, names_to = "date", values_to = "capacity") %>%
            mutate(date_num = my(date),
                   date = toTitleCase(str_replace_all(date, "_20", " "))) %>%
            ungroup() %>%
            mutate(date = reorder(date, date_num)) %>%
            dplyr::filter(!!group_variable %in% variable_list)
        

        
        fig <- plot_ly(base_data, x = ~date, y = ~capacity, type = 'scatter', mode = "line", name = ~{{group_variable}}, color = ~{{group_variable}}) %>%
            layout(title = list(text = title), legend = list(orientation = 'h', x = .5, xanchor = "center", y = -.3))
        
        fig


    }
    
    
    
    output$distPlot <- renderPlotly({
        just_projects <- my_data %>%
            dplyr::select(project)
        
        resource_plots(my_data, names(just_projects), input$group_choice, "Will it ever work?")
        
    })
}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

**Edit:** I further reduced down my code and put it above. I now get a new error:

```
Warning: Error in unique.default: unique() applies only to vectors
```

This is strange to me because the function doesn't call `unique()`--the only sections that do in the UI run perfectly.

**Edit 2** I implemented the changes recommended by stefan. I know don't get any warning messages--but it also doesn't show me a plot:

```
library(shiny)
library(plotly)
library(dplyr)
library(rlang)
library(stringr)

my_data <- tibble(employee = c("Justin", "Corey","Sibley", "Justin", "Corey","Sibley", "Lisa", "NA"),
                  education = c("graudate", "student", "student", "student", "student", "student", "student", "student"),
                  fte_max_capacity = c(1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5),
                  project = c("big", "medium", "small", "medium", "small", "small", "medium", "medium"),
                  aug_2021 = c(2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 5),
                  sep_2021 = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 50),
                  oct_2021 = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 12),
                  nov_2021 = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 10))

# Define UI for application that draws a histogram
ui <- fluidPage(
    
    # Sidebar with a slider input for number of bins 
    sidebarLayout(
        sidebarPanel(
            selectInput("group_choice", label = h3("group_choice"), 
                        choices = unique(my_data$project),
                        selected = unique(my_data$project),
                        multiple = TRUE),
            selectInput("resource_choice", label = h3("resource_choice"), 
                        choices = unique(my_data$employee),
                        multiple = TRUE)),
        
        # Show a plot of the generated distribution
        mainPanel(
            plotOutput("distPlot")
        )
    )
)


# Define server logic required to draw a histogram
server <- function(input, output) {
    
    
    
    employee_list <- c(NA_character_)
    
    employee_list <- reactive({
        req(input$resource_choice)
        input$resource_choice
    })
    
    
    resource_plots <- function(data, group_variable, group_filter = NULL, title) {
        
        group_variable <- sym(group_variable)

        base_data <- data %>%
            dplyr::group_by(!!group_variable) %>%
            summarise_at(vars(contains("_20")), sum, na.rm = TRUE) %>%
            pivot_longer(-{{group_variable}}, names_to = "date", values_to = "capacity") %>%
            mutate(date_num = my(date),
                   date = toTitleCase(str_replace_all(date, "_20", " "))) %>%
            ungroup() %>%
            mutate(date = reorder(date, date_num)) %>%
            dplyr::filter(!!group_variable %in% input$group_choice)
        
        some_colors <- c("#CA001B", "#1D28B0", "#D71DA4", "#00A3AD", "#FF8200", "#753BBD", "#00B5E2", "#008578", "#EB6FBD", "#FE5000", "#6CC24A", "#D9D9D6", "#AD0C27", "#950078")
        
        line_chart_text_format <- list(
            family = "Arial",
            size = 10)
        
        title_format <- list(
            family = "Arial",
            size = 16)

        
        fig <-   eval_tidy(
            quo_squash(
                quo({plot_ly(base_data, x = ~date, y = ~capacity, type = 'scatter', mode = "line", name = ~{{group_variable}}, color = ~{{group_variable}}, colors = ~some_colors[seq_along(unique({{group_variable}}))]) %>%
                        layout(title = list(text = "Capacity by Project Impact"), legend = list(orientation = 'h', x = .5, xanchor = "center", y = -.3))
                })))
        
        fig


    }
    
    
    
    output$distPlot <- renderPlotly({
        just_projects <- my_data %>%
            dplyr::select(project)
        
        resource_plots(my_data, names(just_projects), input$group_choice, "Will it ever work?")
        
    })
}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: The issue is that tidy evaluation using !! and or {{ does not work with plotly. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55505599/combine-formula-and-tidy-eval-plotly for a solution to tackle this issue.

Comment: @stefan, thank you for responding! I tried that solution (see above where I added edit2). It not doesn't give any error messages (progress!), but it also doesn't know the plot. Any ideas?

Comment: Try with `plotlyOutput` instead of `plotOutput` in your UI.